# Why does my HTML not link with my CSS?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am working on my website, and my HTML isn't linking to my CSS. Can somebody please shed some light on this issue?

This is the snippet from my code.

`<link href="css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

My file directory goes like this.

- /root

  - /css

    - style.css
    - style2.css
  - /html

    - index.html
    - webconfig.html
  - /Images

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you putting it between the `<head>` tags? Usually these problems come down to a pathing issue. It's best to put a forward slash in `/css/style2.css` - this way it will always look from the root of your site for the CSS file.

Answer (score 4):

Your current `href` is a relative path, rooted from where ever the HTML file is.

You can either use a correct, relative path...

```
<link href="../css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Or you can use an absolute (domain-rooted) path...

```
<link href="/css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

... assuming your website is deployed at the root of your domain.

Answer (score 0):

The link you have is relative, so it starts looking in the same folder as your html. You could do an absolute path to the css with `/css/style2.css` or use a relative path `../css/style2.css`

Answer (score 0):

Use **relative URL** `<link href="../css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

The url **css/style2.css** should be  relative to the HTML file(the file that contains code  `<link href="css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`) .

`..`  in  above relative URL indicates go one folder back, and then to the css folder - and in that css folder use style2.css file.

Similarly `../../` , means go two folders back and so on.